# Something missing in the Expression Language (EL) syntax for calling a function in a Java class

Tags: jsf, xpages

I've used [Expression Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language)'s (EL)`myUnmanagedBean.fn()` to compute the text for the label of a link from a Java class. Where myUnmanagedBean is the name of the bean.

The function is,

```
private static String s="vijay";

static String fn()
{
    return s;
}
```

I've added a data context to an xpage and the corresponding code is:

```
<xp:this.dataContexts>
    <xp:dataContext var="myUnmanagedBean"
        value="${javascript:new com.kkmsoft.vijay.Invoke1()}">
    </xp:dataContext>
</xp:this.dataContexts>
```

The error page shows:

```
Exception:

myUnmanagedBean.fn()
Encountered "(", expected one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||", "?"]
Encountered "(" at line 1, column 21. Was expecting one of: "}" ... "." ... ">" ... "gt" ... "<" ... "lt" ... "==" ... "eq" ... "<=" ... "le" ... ">=" ... "ge" ... "!=" ... "ne" ... "[" ... "+" ... "-" ... "*" ... "/" ... "div" ... "%" ... "mod" ... "and" ... "&&" ... "or" ... "||" ... "?" ...
```

And in the stacktrace,

```
javax.faces.el.ReferenceSyntaxException: myUnmanagedBean.fn()
com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.checkSyntax(Unknown Source)
```

That datacontext is just for test purposes; I know it's not an ideal method to do so.
What is the problem?

Comment: Protip: Don't pick a heading for your question that makes a claim about a language/pattern that only reveals your lack of understanding. If you don't understand something, put a question: e.g. How to call a Java function from EL

Comment: I was about to mean in "my EL code". Now only i noted it. Regrets.

Comment: "Unified Expression Language" (the new thingy) or "Expression Language" (the old thingy)? [Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language).

Answer (score 1):

1. Your EL is wrong. Remove the brackets.
2. You need getters and setters for your value
3. The getters and setters can not be static
4. If you want to use the viewScope for your data context, you need to implement *java.io.Serializable*

Comment: The above pts satisfied. Now Property not found exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Sven is right. Your code isn't a Bean (it looks very much like [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)). A bean:

- has a default constructor without parameters
- has get and set function pairs (if you omit set, it is a read-only property)

The EL expression you would use is `myUnmanagedBean.fn`

```
   package com.kkmsoft.vijay;
   //Import statements omitted

   public class Invoke1 implements Serializable {

        private String s="vijay";

        public String getFn() {
            return this.s;
        }

        // Optional
        public String setFn(String newS) {
            this.s = newS;
        }
   }
```

Note: fn is small in the EL, but getFn requires a capital F.

Comment: the code is right and i used getters and setters for the string value. Now i used, "myUnmanagedBean.getS". It throws Property Not Found Exception. Error getting property 'S1' from bean of type com.kkmsoft.vijay.Invoke1

Comment: @vijay The new error you're reporting doesn't match the syntax you're claiming. `#{myUnmanagedBean.getS}` would try to call `Invoke1.getGetS()`, or `Invoke1.setGetS()`, depending on whether it's a read or write context. In contrast, `#{myUnmanagedBean.fn}` would try to call `Invoke1.getFn()` or `Invoke1.setFn()` based on read/write context. Sorry to be snarky, but there's a wealth of information about this syntax already out there... for the XPages questions you've asked so far, you might want to visit Google first before you visit stackoverflow.